# Random Permutation polynomial

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

I need to know, please:

(1) Is there anyway to pick uniformly at random permutation polynomial in a field of prime order?

(2) Are there many permutation polynomials in a field?

(3)  In a finite field of q elements how many bijective polynomials exist whose degree are smaller than d ?

***Indeed has the permutation polynomial used in this way in cryptography to generate uniformly random value? If yes, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Are there many permutation polynomials in a field?*

For a field $F$ of order $q$, every function from $F$ to $F$ is expressable (uniquely) as a polynomial of order $q-1$.  $q!$ of these will represent permutation polynomials.

*Is there anyway to pick uniformly at random permutation polynomial in a field of prime order?*

Given a function from $f$ with $f(x_i) = y_i$, it's not difficult to write the polynomial that generates it.  It's just a sum of terms like $(x y_0/x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)... + (x - x_0)(xy_1/x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)...$.  If you are generating the permutation on the fly, you can compose simpler permutation polynomials.  I don't know if there are more efficient methods.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference proving that q! is the number of permutation polynomial in a field.

Comment: @user153465: There are $q!$ permutations on a set of $q$ elements; for each permutation, there is an unique order $q-1$ (or shorter) polynomial where the output of the polynimial is the input permutated by that permutation; QED

Comment: Right, the $q!$ part is just counting the permutations. Proving it fully does require the fact that all functions are expressible as polynomials.  This follows from the construction I gave, though there are better proofs (that escape me right now).  Note that the limit on the order of the polynomial comes from $x^q = x$.

Comment: I'd like extent the above question to below and have your answers: In a finite field of q elements how many permutation polynomials exist whose degree are smaller than d ?

Comment: 1) That's different enough that you should probably ask separately 2) I don't know 3) it doesn't really sound like a crypto question anymore, http://mathoverflow.net might get you better answers.

Comment: @bmm6o It might be relevant to crypto. Consider one who defines a poly. $f_1$ on a field and evaluate at some points $X$ to obtain a set of values $Y$. To make the elements in $Y$ uniformly at random he picks a random bijective poly. of degree equal to smaller than degree of $f_1$. So to prove this is secure he needs to know the number of random bijective poly whose degree are specified as above. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not convinced that limiting the degree of the polynomial serves a purpose, and you have the problem that low-order permutation polynomials aren't going to be very random. $x + a$ defines a permutation for every $a$, but it's just a set of permutations of size $p$.